# Why does Python pointing change with small changes to this function?

Tags: python, class, methods, attr

when working with python, it bothered me that while obj.method() is perfectly fine, method(obj) isn't allowed. So I figured I'd try to write some code to fix that. I came up with the next:

```
def globalclassfuncs(defobj):
  for i in inspect.getmembers(defobj, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    def scope():
      var = i[0];
      setattr(sys.modules[__name__], i[0], lambda obj, *args: getattr(obj, var)(*args));
    scope();
```

However, there's something weird with this. When I remove `def scope():` and `scope()`, so that it'll run without a function definition in the for loop, or when I change the `getattr()` function to use `i[0]` directly instead of through `var`, somehow all new defined functions point to the last defined function instead of the function they should point to. Why does this behaviour change so much on such small changes in the code?

Comment: “Fix” that, huh? Please don’t. Judging by the semicolons, you’re used to something else, but this is not a good idea in Python.

Comment: @minitech May I ask why this wouldn't be a good idea?

Comment: why would you want to do something so horrible to begin with?

Comment: @StefanoBorini just out of curiosity whether I'd be able to write such a thing.

Comment: I guess the next step is writing a metaclass that wraps `__init__` to run this. *sigh*

Comment: Well, you _can_ use the `method(obj)` syntax, it's just a bit different: `ClassName.method(obj)`. Yeah, but why would you do that?

Comment: Fair enough. It's weird, but the language allows you to do so. It's stuff like this that allow you to understand how it works. In any case, it's a common python gotcha when dealing with closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a case of [late binding closure](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/)